# jQuery - Cannot change html content of this element

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Im using plugin http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html and I would like to change 'Todays month' to display prev/next month name once you have clicked on prev/next button.

Graphically i want this:

[image]

**JS:**

```
$('#defaultPopup').datepick({
onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            var changed_date = $.datepick.formatDate('MM', new Date(month+'.01.'+year));
            $('.datepick a.datepick-cmd-today').html(changed_date);
            console.log(changed_date); //works
        },
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/zcaL005y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works, but it seems that the datepicker is overriding your changes. Maybe it is setting the HTML of that element again, after your code has run.

For proof, you can try throwing an error after your `console.log` statement. This will prevent further code from running, and you can actually see the HTML of the current month changed to the value you set:

```
$('#defaultPopup').datepick({
  onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
    var changed_date = $.datepick.formatDate('MM', new Date(month + '.01.' + year));
    $('.datepick a.datepick-cmd-today').html(changed_date);
    console.log(changed_date); //works
    throw 'test error'; // throw error here to prevent further code running
  },
});
```

I've updated your fiddle with this change, refer to [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/zcaL005y/5/) to see it in action.

Comment: The date returns undefined because it's not well formatted. Here's the correction => http://jsfiddle.net/zcaL005y/12/

Comment: @vyx.ca -- Remove the `throw`, and it will stop working.

Comment: Yes that's because the calendar is completely rerendered after his code is ran. You can easily test this by manually changing "today" in the dom inspector to another string of text and then click on "next". When you do that, "Today" will appear again. This validates that the calendar is rendered again on a change. The method "onChangeMonthYear" is executed and then the calendar is rendered, loosing the change. Your code was correct, I just wanted to point out that OP's code contained an error and fixed it within your code.

Comment: Too bad this cant be solved in another, more proper, way.

Comment: @RhymeGuy -- I didn't mean this. This problem may be solved in a proper way, but that will need digging into the source/documentation of the datepicker, which I wasn't willing to do.